# Changing viewport/screen width js

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport

I've been trying to build a responsive button on our new website which changes the body width to 460px for example to show what our website looks like on mobile. I've seen this done using iframes as the iframe width sets the viewport width so a button can set a width of the iframe and it will change and look responsive.

I'm trying to do this with vanilla javascript but struggling. I can set the body width no problem, but bootstrap and the css media queries don't respect setting a width as it works off of viewport/screen width which remains the same.

How do I do this? I have a button of a mobile, and a button of a desktop and they should adjust the screens width to mobile/desktop widths and the media queries should respect it.

Is this possible? My viewport is set as:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

and media queries as:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {}
```

Comment: You could use an iframe?

Comment: @evolutionxbox not possible, this is for our primary site and as an SEO agency, this would be suicide to our rankings.

Comment: Afaik, we can’t change the width of a page using js that wasn’t first created by js.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I just learnt a new abbreviation! Thanks. I've seen snippets that suggest things like "$('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=400');" but no idea how to use this as it had no context when I found it.

Comment: Try changing the meta tag viewport content to something random on a button click?

Comment: @sitecentre An `iframe` is the correct solution.  It's wild that you're more concerned with SEO than actually solving the problem.  If you really are an SEO agency, perhaps you'd know that crawlers know what an iframe is.  No, you cannot set the viewport otherwise.  You'll have to rework your CSS without the media queries if you refuse to use an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't get you wrong about your case, I have 2 recommend for you.

- Use function `open` to open the new window that is fully loaded in desired width and height. You can take a look at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

  ```
  var option_string = "location=yes,width=640,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
  var URL = "https://your_link.com";
  var win = window.open(URL, "_blank", option_string );
  ```
- Instead of loading your full page, use iframe of page which you want to display and embed, after click `Desktop` or `Mobile` button, change the width of iframe depend on which button is clicked. Take a look at example below for more details:

  ```
  <body>
      <iframe id="your_site" src="https://your_link.com">
      <button class="btn btn_desktop">Desktop</button>
      <button class="btn btn_mobile">Mobile</button>
      <script>
          var $iframe = document.getElementById('your_site');
          var $resize_button = document.getElementByClass('btn');
          $resize_button.on('click', function(e){
              var $button = e.target;
              if (button.classList.contains('btn_desktop')) { // bigger your frame
                  $iframe.style.width = '640px'; 
              } else {
                  $iframe.style.width = 'auto';
              }
          })
      </script>
  </body>
  ```

Hope it would help

Comment: The iframe option isn't an option as this is a primary site designed for SEO purposes, the popup option really doesn't give us the desired visual effect it's meant to but great suggestion. I may have to scrap my idea :(